# Extending laptop across 3 monitors

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi

I currently have a Sager NP9150 gaming laptop. The machine comes with a DVI, HDMI, and display port. I currently have a Dell monitor and a TV connected - the monitor with a DVI and the TV with a vga to Display Port adapter. For some reason though I am unable to extend the desktop across the three monitors or use all three in some fashion. Is there a specific piece of hardware or software I need to enable more than one additional monitor?

Specs:
Sager NP9150
Processor: i7-3610QM 2.3 Ghz
16gb  RAM
WIN 7 64 bit OS
Nvidia GTX 670M and IntelR HD Graphics 4000

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a docking station you should try to connect one monitor to the dockingstation and the others to the laptop. With 2 monitors it worked for me using a lenovo notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Some systems will not do this, its some kind of limitation of the hardware and or the software. I've seen this on many makes and models. Some will do three screens, some won't. I know you have Nvidia chipset, but many times it's just something that can't be worked around.

Answer (score 1):

Most graphics cards support a maximum of two screens at a time, even if you have enough video outputs to handle more.  On a desktop, the easy way around this would be to install a 2nd video card.  This is obviously more difficult to do on a laptop.  The only way I know of to get a 2nd video card for a laptop is with an external one.

I have used a USB-to-DVI card, [similar to this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815101012&Tpk=evga%20usb%20video%20card&IsVirtualParent=1), for years.  It works well, but I don't know if it would hold up for gaming (mine plays video fine, but I haven't tried gaming with it).  You may be able to find some that run on a PC Card slot or a mini-PCIe, if your laptop has either, but I have no experience with that type of card.